# How to get row values from selected row in a Data Table in R Shiny App

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I need to get the selected row 1st column value from the DT Data Table. Using, *DataTable_rows_selected* , I am able to get the selected row count, Now I am looking for ways to extract the row values from the data table. In the example below, there are two *observeEvent* based on action button, 1st observe event is import and displays the data and 2nd one needs to display the selected row 1st col value so that I can use the same achieve other features. Please note,In Actual Application, the imported data is a web service API and which  I am parsing in R and converting to data frame.

## Sample Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Data Table Example"),
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem('Tabs', tabName='tabs',
           menuSubItem('Tab 1', tabName='tab1'),
           menuSubItem('Tab 2', tabName='tab2')
  )
)
),

dashboardBody(

tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName='tab1',
          actionButton("import","Import"),
          br(),
          tags$div(tags$h3(tags$b(" Get Selected Row Values",align="middle",style="color: rgb(57,156,8)"))),
          br(),
          DT::dataTableOutput('ProductDataTable')
  ),
  tabItem(tabName='tab2',
          actionButton("display","Display"),
          uiOutput('info')
   )
 )
 )
 )

server <- function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$import,{

Product <- read.csv2("RulesData.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")

output$ProductDataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({

DT::datatable(Product,selection = "single",

                extensions = c('Buttons', 'ColReorder', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'),
                rownames=FALSE,
                options=list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                             searching = T,
                             pageLength = 25,
                             searchHighlight = TRUE,
                             colReorder = TRUE,
                             fixedHeader = TRUE,
                             filter = 'bottom',
                             buttons = c('copy', 'csv','excel', 'print'),
                             paging    = TRUE,
                             deferRender = TRUE,
                             scroller = TRUE,
                             scrollX = TRUE,
                             scrollY = 700

                ))
})

})

observeEvent(input$display,{

row_count <- input$ProductDataTable_rows_selected

output$info <- renderPrint({

  cat('Row Selected: ')
  cat(row_count, sep = ', ')
  cat(Product[1,2], sep = ', ')


 })

})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4):

check this code below if this is what You are looking for:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Data Table Example"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('Tabs', tabName='tabs',
               menuSubItem('Tab 1', tabName='tab1'),
               menuSubItem('Tab 2', tabName='tab2')
      )
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName='tab1',
              actionButton("import","Import"),
              br(),
              tags$div(tags$h3(tags$b(" Get Selected Row Values",align="middle",style="color: rgb(57,156,8)"))),
              br(),
              DT::dataTableOutput('ProductDataTable')
      ),
      tabItem(tabName='tab2',
              actionButton("display","Display"),
              uiOutput('info')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  Product <- reactive({mtcars})

  observeEvent(input$import,{


    output$ProductDataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({

      DT::datatable(Product(),selection = "single",

                    extensions = c('Buttons', 'ColReorder', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'),
                    rownames=FALSE,
                    options=list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                 searching = T,
                                 pageLength = 25,
                                 searchHighlight = TRUE,
                                 colReorder = TRUE,
                                 fixedHeader = TRUE,
                                 filter = 'bottom',
                                 buttons = c('copy', 'csv','excel', 'print'),
                                 paging    = TRUE,
                                 deferRender = TRUE,
                                 scroller = TRUE,
                                 scrollX = TRUE,
                                 scrollY = 700

                    ))
    })

  })

  observeEvent(input$display,{


    output$info <- renderPrint({
      row_count <- input$ProductDataTable_rows_selected
      data <- Product()[row_count, ] 
      cat('Row Selected: ')
      cat(data[,1]) #display the selected row 1st col value  


    })

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have used `mtcars` dataset as an example, the problem was that Your data was inside of the `observer` (one with `input$import`) and as You need to use it for other analysis such as displaying of the row value of first column (i have not understood well what did You mean about that as Your code is telling different thing), data had to be moved outside of the `observer` and put into `reactive`.

**[UPDATE]**

I have used `if` statement to import the data instead of `observeEvent`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Data Table Example"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('Tabs', tabName='tabs',
               menuSubItem('Tab 1', tabName='tab1'),
               menuSubItem('Tab 2', tabName='tab2')
      )
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName='tab1',
              actionButton("import","Import"),
              br(),
              tags$div(tags$h3(tags$b(" Get Selected Row Values",align="middle",style="color: rgb(57,156,8)"))),
              br(),
              DT::dataTableOutput('ProductDataTable')
      ),
      tabItem(tabName='tab2',
              actionButton("display","Display"),
              uiOutput('info')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  Product <- reactive({
    if(input$import == 0)
  {
    return()
  }
    isolate({
      input$import
      data <- mtcars # Here read Your data: read.csv2("RulesData.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
      })
  })


    output$ProductDataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({

      DT::datatable(Product(),selection = "single",

                    extensions = c('Buttons', 'ColReorder', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'),
                    rownames=FALSE,
                    options=list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                 searching = T,
                                 pageLength = 25,
                                 searchHighlight = TRUE,
                                 colReorder = TRUE,
                                 fixedHeader = TRUE,
                                 filter = 'bottom',
                                 buttons = c('copy', 'csv','excel', 'print'),
                                 paging    = TRUE,
                                 deferRender = TRUE,
                                 scroller = TRUE,
                                 scrollX = TRUE,
                                 scrollY = 700

                    ))
    })


  observeEvent(input$display,{


    output$info <- renderPrint({
      row_count <- input$ProductDataTable_rows_selected
      data <- Product()[row_count, ] 
      cat('Row Selected: ')
      cat(data[,1]) #display the selected row 1st col value  


    })

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.Based on the observe Event, I need to import the data as I need to get the data from Web Service API based on action button trigger. I can not take my data out side and make it reactive as it will add overhead on shiny app performance at the start itself. I am looking for some callback option in data table itself to capture the col value of the selected row.

Comment: Wait a second i will update the answer, i do have better idea then using `observerEvent`

Comment: Check it out, i have used `if` statement to import the data, which is going to work exactly like `observeEvent` --> trigger the data import after button is clicked

Comment: Thank you for suggesting alternative way. I will try this part in actual application and get back to you. For now, it seems one of the option.

Answer (score 2):

one more way to get row values from Data Table is DT:DataTable **Call Back option** in association with Java Script JS().

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Data Table Example"),
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem('Tabs', tabName='tabs',
           menuSubItem('Tab 1', tabName='tab1'),
           menuSubItem('Tab 2', tabName='tab2')
  )
)
),

dashboardBody(

tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName='tab1',
          actionButton("import","Import"),
          br(),
          tags$div(tags$h3(tags$b("Get Selected Row Values",style="color: rgb(57,156,8)"))),
          br(),
          DT::dataTableOutput('ProductDataTable')
  ),
  tabItem(tabName='tab2',
          actionButton("display","Display"),
          uiOutput('info')
  )
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$import,{

Product <- mtcars

output$ProductDataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({

  DT::datatable(Product,selection = "single",
  # JS using call back function to get the row values on single click
                callback = JS("table.on('click.dt', 'tr',
                  function() {
                  Shiny.onInputChange('rows', table.rows(this).data().toArray());
                  });"),

                extensions = c('Buttons', 'ColReorder', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'),
                rownames=FALSE,
                options=list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                             searching = T,
                             pageLength = 25,
                             searchHighlight = TRUE,
                             colReorder = TRUE,
                             fixedHeader = TRUE,
                             filter = 'bottom',
                             buttons = c('copy', 'csv','excel', 'print'),
                             paging    = TRUE,
                             deferRender = TRUE,
                             scroller = TRUE,
                             scrollX = TRUE,
                             scrollY = 700

                ))
})

})

observeEvent(input$display,{

row_count <- input$ProductDataTable_rows_selected

output$info <- renderPrint({
  cat('Row Selected 1st Col Value: ')
  # getting 1st row col value
  cat(input$rows[1], sep = ', ')

})

})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```