# R Shiny : Get data from selected row

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I want to extract data from a table for use in a calculation.

My starting point is
https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html

Essentially I want be able to select a row (say row 8) and from that get model = "a4 quattro" and trans = "manual(m5)".

I've looked for [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756416/how-to-get-row-values-from-selected-row-in-a-data-table-in-r-shiny-app) but can't see how to apply this.  It seems very complex for what (in my view) should be simple.

This is my first day on my first R-shiny application and I'm definitely lost.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete example based on the Shiny example you referenced. This uses `mpg` data from `ggplot2`.

First, you can create a `reactive` expression to determine which rows should be filtered and shown in the table. Whenever one of your `input`s change, then the `reactive` expression will be reevaluated. To access the filtered data, you can reference as `filtered_rows()` (note the parentheses).

To get the selected rows, you can use `input$table_rows_selected` since your `dataTableOutput` is called `table` (just append "_rows_selected"). This can be one or more than one rows, and returns row numbers (e.g., 8 in your example above). Then, to extract your data, you can use `filtered_rows()[input$table_rows_selected, c("model", "trans")]` which will include `model` and `trans` column data for the filtered rows.

The `verbatimTextOutput` and `toString` simply show the results for validation and demonstration. You can use the results in another context as well.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),
  
  # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           selectInput("man",
                       "Manufacturer:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(mpg$manufacturer))))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput("trans",
                       "Transmission:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(mpg$trans))))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput("cyl",
                       "Cylinders:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(mpg$cyl))))
    )
  ),
  # Create a new row for the table.
  DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Filter data based on selections
  filtered_rows <- reactive({
    data <- mpg
    if (input$man != "All") {
      data <- data[data$manufacturer == input$man,]
    }
    if (input$cyl != "All") {
      data <- data[data$cyl == input$cyl,]
    }
    if (input$trans != "All") {
      data <- data[data$trans == input$trans,]
    }
    data
  })
  
  # Show filtered data in the datatable
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({ filtered_rows() }))
  
  # Show selected text
  output$text <- renderText({ toString(filtered_rows()[input$table_rows_selected, c("model", "trans")]) })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That's great!  I knew it had to be something simple.  Just one further point ... what decides if it is one row or many that is selected?

Comment: There are a number of options for `datatable` you can use, check out with `?datatable`...for example, if you try `datatable(filtered_rows(), selection = "single")` you will be able to only select one and not multiple...

Comment: Many thanks - I had seen selection = "single" but wasn't sure how to apply it.

This really helps